# Why is Grails (in Tomcat) logging to both catalina.out and my custom file appender?

Tags: tomcat, grails, log4j

I have the following for my log4j DSL configuration in Grails 1.2:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console name: 'stdout', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: conversionPattern)

        environments {
            production {
                // ... some code to determine file path ...

                rollingFile name: 'file', file: "${logDirectory}/${appName}.log", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: conversionPattern)
                rollingFile name: 'StackTrace', file: "${logDirectory}/${appName}-stacktrace.log"
        }
    }

    environments {
        development { root { warn 'stdout' } }
        test { root { warn 'stdout' } }
        production { root { error 'file' } }
    }

    // ... package-specific logging configurations ...
}
```

When I deploy as a war to Tomcat, my logs get written to both catalina.out and my 'file' logger defined for production.

I've tried:

- adding `additivity = false` to the `root {}` definition for `production {}`, which doesn't work (and I wouldn't really expect it to, since it's apparently setting additivity for the root logger itself?).
- defining the 'stdout' console appender inside of a `development {}` and `test {}` block within the `appenders {}` closure, but that doesn't work either.

Perhaps this is an issue with my Tomcat configuration and not my log4j DSL? The closest I've come to finding someone with a similar issue is [this mailing-list thread](http://n4.nabble.com/log4j-additivity-DSL-Grails-1-1-td1383642.html), for which there was no (simple) solution.

**How can I prevent logs from being written to catalina.out in production?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to work around the issue by doing the following in `Config.groovy`:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

log4j = {
    // ... configuration from question ...
}

environments {
    production {
        def logger = Logger.getRootLogger()
        logger.removeAppender('stdout')
    }
}
```

However, this feels like a dirty hack, and I'm hoping there's a better, Grails log4j DSL-specific way to do this.

Also, anything the application might happen to write to stdout will probably not get written, which might be a bad thing if there are logs/exceptions/stacktraces being somehow written directly to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

In grails 2.4.5 you can define a 'null' appender for stdout

https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.x/guide/conf.html#logging

```
log4j = {
    ...
    appenders {
        'null' name: 'stdout'
    }
    ...
}
```